# Kinect with rviz

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner of both ROS, Kinect and Ubuntu. What i want is to visualize kinect data on rviz environment then run object recognition on it.

I've tried a few tutorials but had no luck. All I got was an empty rviz world.

Since I am a beginner I would appreciate any step-by-step intructions (preferably for hydro or groovy).

I would also like to note that I've menaged to get visual from kinect so the device is working fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111536/kinect-with-rviz/) by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install the package fro kinect run:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch
```

The to use: `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) to make the package publish kinect's topics.
To visualize for example the depth image run `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image`.

To visualize for example the Point Cloud in rviz you can add a PointCloud2 Display ad choose the appropriate topic. For object recognition what are you planning to use?

I suggest you to see also the basic [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and the [rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials) tutorials!

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on 2013-12-19**:
Hello and thank you for your reply. I've managed to get the visual from kinect however still can't see it on rviz.  For example, after running the depth image i set fixed frame on rviz to depth frame but nothing changes. What else do I need to do ?

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on 2013-12-20**:
Nvm, fixed it. Ty for your help.